# How to add a dependency to internet to a service with systemd on arch?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, openvpn

My openVPN connection start perfectly on boot with connman service for Internet and openVPN for my vpn connection.

But, If I boot with a connection to Internet at boot and after many time I disconnect for a moment and reconnect after. Since I disconnect, the openVPN service will still run. And when I reconnect to Internet, I must manually `systemctl restart openvpn@<configName>.service`.

So, I get a idea: set a dependency to internet to my openvpn service. But how ? My connman service will still run when I didn't have connection. So I can't use the `Requires=` on `/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn\@.service` ([see wiki arch for more details](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Handling_dependencies))

So is there a way to set a dependency to Internet to a service ? And auto stop/start the service when the Internet state change ?

Comment: when you go offline you still have an ip defined? if not you can put a dependency Wants=network-online.target and After=network-online.target

Comment: When I do `systemctl | grep network` I get only one result: `network.target` and I just tested now, there isn't difference when I have or not Internet.

Comment: if you start network-online.target `systemctl start network-online.target` will change the result of `systemctl status network-online.target`  when you are online or offline?

Comment: I was able to enable and start the service `network-online.target` but the status is always active, Internet or no.

Comment: @LilloX: requiring `network-online.target` won't help, the target doesn't deactivate itself when the connection is gone.